# Access to button from Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard

Stupid and simple question, but I have to ask.

I dragged on Storyboard a button.
How to get access to it?
With drag "Ctrl" not offer.
How do I do it programmatically change setVisible(Yes/No)?

Comment: What are you actually want?

Comment: I have Storyboard.
Button on it.
How to bind a button to (UIButton *myButton).

Answer (score 2):

You need an IBOutlet to your UIButton

in your view controller h file

```
IBOutlet UIButton *mybutton;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *mybutton;
```

in your m file

```
@synthesize mybutton;
```

and then you should be able to do:

```
[mybutton setAlpha:0];
```

Comment: I have a lot of buttons.
How can I distinguish between them?
I need access to a single button.

Comment: Make multiple uibutton IVARS UIButton *mybutton1, *mybutton2 etc then you can link them in the storyboard appropriately